# Routing with next.js SSR renders a blank screen before showing the page

Tags: routes, next.js, server-side-rendering

I know that my data is being on server side and then my screen is going to be rendered, but is it possible to avoid this?

I'm already using next/link instead an a tag

Comment: For clarification, are you asking if you can use Next without server-side rendering?  Or are you saying that you have to server-side render some content, but since that takes longer to load, you want to avoid a blank screen for the user while they wait?

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear, english is not my native language
I have to server-side render the content, and I wanna know if theres a way to avoid the blank screen for the users, like a SPA.
I heard that next/link would do the trick but I got the same result as an classic <a> tag

Comment: Can you post your code please?  Here is an example of using next/link with SSR, and  the page does not go blank.  https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-dewdney-rv4qd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next.js will not return blank page and then rehydrate it. It will resolve the page once it gets data for new page. So transition will look like with any other server side rendering technology, user will stay on previous page as long as the new one is not loaded.

If that doesn't suit you, you can always extend your _app.js and add custom loaders/animation in between page transitions.